# Windows 8 Hidden Downloading? Slow Internet?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8

After upgrading to Windows 8, im facing a very slow download speed. My router and the NIC is working fine because on the same PC I also have Linux. In Linux, everything works fine.

When checking through the task manager, it shows that the system use the full bandwidth 1Mbps even without a download. The process menu doesn't show whats taking much bandwidth. The bitdefender's firewall also shows network activity.

Is there any hidden apps downloading? How to fix this?

Comment: try typing 'netstat' in a command prompt or powershell to see your connections.

Comment: Or Resource Monitor from Task Manager. Oh wait, even the Process tab in Task Manager would show you the usage of each process. To fix it? Just let it download whatever it need all night long, afterwards it would behave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start resource monitor, click the networking tab and check which processes are utilising the network the most.

If you don't want this process to run you should check the correct way to stop whatever is downloading to stop running.